# Page is posted back when client confirmation is false on image button inside a grid

Tags: c#, gridview, templatefield

Does Any body know why a page is posted back  ( ImageButtonClick event fires) when client confirmation( javascript) is false

EventValidation is disabled for the page

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="remove" runat ="server"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you really want to remove this candidate from the Written test shortlist?');" ToolTip="Remove this candidate"  
                                ImageUrl="~/images/Delete.gif" onclick="remove_Click" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you set any value in ItemDataBound Event? Do you have any other JavaScript/jquery functions in this page which might Change the Attribute? Check the generated html aslo

Comment: Thiis the kind of HTML Generated for the button <a onclick="return  confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Remove this candidate?&#39;);" id="MainContent_gvApplicants_remove_0" title="Remove this  applicant if duplicate" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$gvApplicants$ctl02$remove&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Delete</a>

Comment: Thank you guys ,
the issue was that I had this code  which is used to enable row selection  with a row click event, but unintentionally  changes the  onclick event on the on the button as well. I commented that out and worked fine,

Answer (score 1):

Write return false in your javascript function that called at the time of click

Comment: I Actually have  the "return confirm('')" js on the "OnClientClick" attribute of the image see the edited question

Comment: you had write on onclick of button so it will post back if u want to do confirm then u need to call one js function and from then u need to mange like 
 function abc() {
            var r = confirm("Press a button!");
            if (r == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

Comment: I have seen that the confirm returns true  or false based on what I click(yes/no) the thing is when it is a no it deletes the record